# Definite integration using int command

Tags: matlab, integral

Firstly, I'm quite new to Matlab.
I am currently trying to do a definite integral with respect to y of a particular function. The function that I want to integrate is

[image: this]

(note that the big parenthesis is multiplying with the first factor - I can't get the latex to not make it look like power)

I have tried plugging the above integral into Desmos and it worked as intended. My plan was to vary the value of x and y and will be using for loop via matlab.
However, after trying to use the int function to calculate the definite integral with the code as follow:

```
h = 5; 
a = 2; 
syms y
x = 3.8; 
p = 2.*x.^2+2.*a.*y;
q = x.^2+y.^2;
r = x.^2+a.^2;
f = (-1./sqrt(1-(p.^2./(4.*q.*r)))).*(2.*sqrt(q).*sqrt(r).*2.*a-p.*2.*y.*sqrt(r)./sqrt(q))./(4.*q.*r);
theta = int(f,y,a+0.01,h) %the integral is undefined at y=2, hence the +0.01
```

the result is not quite as expected

```
theta =
 
int(-((8*461^(1/2)*(y^2 + 361/25)^(1/2))/5 - (461^(1/2)*y*(8*y + 1444/25))/(5*(y^2 + 361/25)^(1/2)))/((1 - (4*y + 722/25)^2/((1844*y^2)/25 + 665684/625))^(1/2)*((1844*y^2)/25 + 665684/625)), y, 21/10, 5)
```

After browsing through various posts, the common mistake is the undefined interval but the +0.01 should have fixed it. Any guidance on what went wrong is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you expecting to get? Perhaps you need to apply the [simplify](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) function

Answer (score 0):

The *Definite Integrals* example in the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.int.html#btybolt-4) shows exactly this type of output when a closed form cannot be computed. You can approximate it numerically using `vpa`, i.e.

```
F = int(f,y,a,h);
theta = vpa(F);
```

Or you can do a numerical computation directly

```
theta = vpaintegral(f,y,a,h);
```

From the docs:

> The vpaintegral function is faster and provides control over integration tolerances.